# Using Elastic Transcoder on local storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My RDS is currently working on AWS instance. There is a Lambda function for uploading and transcoding videos.

Can I change the transcoder to use my local storage instead of an Amazon S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Elastic Transcoder service for transcoding, input file has to on S3. So, you have to upload them to S3. But if you are transcoding your files inside Lambda, a Lambda script can fetch your local server files over simple FTP(for example). But best practice is to upload them to S3 first. You can clean up your S3 files after you are done with them if your concern is storage cost.

Comment: Hi, Am using s3 bucket for storage with elastic transcoder now. But the cost is too high. Thats why am planning to change storage to local server. Is i possible to alter the lambda

Comment: Of course you can but the problem with Lambda is that it has 500mb storage, max 3gb ram and max runtime is 300 seconds. If you are transcoding large videos it will fail

Comment: @Eleenajose What do you mean by "cost is too high"? Is this the cost for storage, or the cost for Elastic Transcoder?